# Выгрузка данных в Excel в php

Tags: export, php, excel

Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты. Передо мной стоит задача автоматизации отчетности в Excel. На первый взгляд около 200 отчетов.

Смотрел в интернете классы для выгрузки, но с помощью них очень долго и "напряжно" делать. Есть ли какая-нибудь универсальная система, может класс, поддерживающий подобие шаблонов?

Еще хотелось бы без ком технологии, потому как виндус сервер не дают на работе.

Жду Ваших советов. Рассмотрю любой вариант.

Comment: Критично именно XL? csv не устроит?

Comment: Хорошо бы, но им нужно красиво.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот тут посмотри http://exls.ru

Кратко:

- поддерживает шаблоны;
- выгружает в форматы .xls, .xls.gz, .zip;
- есть возможность расширять форматы;
- программировать на php не нужно;
- поддерживает входные параметры;
- поддерживает модули (например: выгрузка заголовков почты в excel);
- пойдет на любом хостинге.

Я принимал участие в написании данной системы.

Comment: Хей, он платный! Ай,яй! А как же любовь к миру и все отдам за так?) Ребята, подскажите, стоит нет покупать такой скрипт?

Comment: Спасибо за бонус!

Comment: уже не работает сайт

Answer (score 6):

Есть библиотека [PhpExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), довольно хорошая, сам ей пользовался для такой задачи. Много возможностей (стили, формулы, валидация и т.д.). Объектно-ориентированная. Единственный минус - очень прожорливая для документов с большим количеством стилей. Но проблема решается шаблонами (сам набиваешь в Excel пустой документ со стилями, формулами и т.д.) А php только забивает данными (для этого кроме writer-а имеется reader).
Есть альтернативный вариант [Spreadsheet Excel Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/redirected), он полностью бинарный, поэтому не такой прожорливый по памяти. Но соответственно урезаны возможности. Кроме того затруднена работа с Office 2007 и дальше. Кстати PhpExcel writer5 (для генерации xls (не xlsx) документов, написан на основе Spreadsheet Writer-а.

Так что рекомендую заюзать первую либу и иметь красочные отчёты, чем разбираться со второй.

Comment: Spreadsheet Excel Reader недавно тестил. Документ 11.7мб, простой экспорт в бд (прочитал-записал-обнулил) - сожрал 160мб оперативки при игноре стилей. Без игнора стилей падал до прочтения.

Comment: Попробовал PhpExcel, пока вроде неплохое решение. Но приходиться многостраничный код писать для каждого отчета. Никак не могу понять как использовать готовый файл в качестве шаблона. Прожорливость не смог понять. Отпишусь позднее.
Автору +, правда не хватает прав.
Второй затестить не смогу. Установить что то левое не дадут (левое - имеется ввиду по моей инициативе).

Comment: Набиваешь готовый файл (шапку, стили, формулы суммы например, короче то, что не будет меняться в этом отчёте, всё кроме данных), кладёшь его в папку на сервере. Создаёшь объект
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$objExcel = $objReader->load('путь к файлу');

С $objExcel работаешь как с объектом phpExcel (данными набиваешь и т.д. только с учётом что в нём уже есть та структура, которую ты сделал руками). Ну а потом какбэ сохраняешь его и имеешь отчёт с статичной шапкой-дном-стилями, но динамичными данными

Answer (score 3):

Я тупо делаю так:

```
<HTML xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<HEAD>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <STYLE>
table {
    mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\,";
    mso-displayed-thousand-separator:" ";
}
td {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial;
    border:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.item {
    mso-number-format:Fixed;
    border:0.5pt solid silver;
    white-space: normal;
    font-size:9.0pt;
    padding: 10pt;
}
.header {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    background:gray;
    color:white;
    white-space:normal;
}
.rootCategory {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    border:.5pt solid black;
    background:gray;
    color:white;
}
.category {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    border:.5pt solid windowtext;
    background: silver;
    color: white;
}
b { font-weight: normal }   </STYLE>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
    <x:Name>price1</x:Name>
    <x:WorksheetOptions>
     <x:NoSummaryRowsBelowDetail/>
     <x:Print>
      <x:ValidPrinterInfo/>
      <x:PaperSizeIndex>9</x:PaperSizeIndex>
      <x:VerticalResolution>0</x:VerticalResolution>
     </x:Print>
     <x:Zoom>90</x:Zoom>
     <x:Selected/>
     <x:FreezePanes/>
     <x:FrozenNoSplit/>
     <x:SplitHorizontal>2</x:SplitHorizontal>
     <x:TopRowBottomPane>2</x:TopRowBottomPane>
     <x:SplitVertical>100</x:SplitVertical>
     <x:LeftColumnRightPane>4</x:LeftColumnRightPane>
     <x:ActivePane>0</x:ActivePane>
     <x:Panes>
      <x:Pane>
       <x:Number>3</x:Number>
      </x:Pane>
      <x:Pane>
       <x:Number>1</x:Number>
       <x:ActiveCol>6</x:ActiveCol>
      </x:Pane>
      <x:Pane>
       <x:Number>2</x:Number>
       <x:ActiveRow>2</x:ActiveRow>
      </x:Pane>
      <x:Pane>
       <x:Number>0</x:Number>
       <x:ActiveCol>9</x:ActiveCol>
      </x:Pane>
     </x:Panes>
     <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>
     <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>
     <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>
    </x:WorksheetOptions>
   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
  <x:WindowHeight>7425</x:WindowHeight>
  <x:WindowWidth>14235</x:WindowWidth>
  <x:WindowTopX>480</x:WindowTopX>
  <x:WindowTopY>30</x:WindowTopY>
  <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>
  <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>
 </x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1030"/>
</xml><![endif]--></HEAD>
<body>

<table>
    ТУТ СТРОИМ ТАБЛИЦУ...
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Это мой вариант. В нем кстати есть категории, которые раскрываются при нажатии "+".
MS 2007 открывает без проблем.

Comment: У меня отчеты как то некрасиво смотрятся. Там где данные-сетка, а там где нет, белое полотно. Но спасибо.

Comment: ну тут нужно функции xml подкорректировать и таблицу стилей.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу библиотеки на php которая работает с шаблонами ничего сказать не могу, но есть библиотека [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), она работает на принципе разметки. Не знаю, стоит ли ее использовать с учетом того, что вам нужно сделать 200 отчетов (слишком не простая задача), но для обычной выгрузки в excel на php она подходит более чем.  С помощью нее можно задавать формат ячейкам, работать с формулами, применять оформление и так далее.  Статью, с примером можно посмотреть [здесь](http://web-arxitector.ru/index.php?page=articles-php-PHPExcel).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.