# Выгрузка данных из mysql в excel + сохранить этот файл (+php)

Tags: phpexcel, php, excel, mysql

Добрый день мне нужно доделать выгрзку из mysql в excel, чтобы этот файл сохранялся. Все запросы в mysql написаны. подгружена библиотека. только остается исправить вот эту строку

```
    //отдаем пользователю в браузер
include("PhpExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php");
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($pExcel);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="rate.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

делали все до меня, сама просто ладу не могу дать, может есть вообще какие-нить другие варианты выгрузки этой данных из базы sql.

Вообще как можно сделать выгрузку файлов не используя сторнних библиотек.???

Comment: Что есть сторонние библиотеки? excel само может это сделать, если установлен odbc-драйвер для mysql. Запросы там вроде можно произвольные писать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Обсуждалось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/30730/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-excel-%D0%B2-php) и не раз, почему никто не пользуется поиском?

Comment: так мне же нужно, чтобы выгрузка из mysql шла.

Comment: Ну так в чем проблема, там все написано!

> только остается исправить вот эту строку

Какую именно строку я их 6 штук вижу.